# Why is __constructor needed in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Why does `__constructor` code needs to run in codeigniter controller and models ? Without those lines, the code is working fine. I am confused !

```
function __construct()
     {
          parent::__construct();
     }
```

Comment: because PHP doesn't call ancestor constructors by default. YOUR object may not need to have a constructor explicitly run, but whatever your object is inheriting from **MAY** need one to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind for using the `_construct(magic Function)` is to load your library and helpers through the controllers, so that you don't have to load libraries and helpers in each of your functions.

Example:

```
function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->library('someclass');
   $this->load->helper('someclass');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work as long as the class from your controller/model does not need it's constructor method to be called. If the class from where it extends defines dependencies needed (for example), you may get unwanted results.
Even though the constructor method is a so called "magic method" and it will be called automatically when you use the `new` keyword (note that you have to use parenthesis):

```
$foo = new Foo();
```

This does not mean that the class from where `Foo` is extending will get it's constructor method called automatically.